# Asterisk Dialplan preventing dialplan from repeating continuously

Tags: asterisk

I have the following macro in my diaplan which is excuted each time an incoming call comes.

Problem is that it is repeating itself indefinitely. I want it to repeat 3 times, if no input from the user, it should say goodbye and quit. Could anyone help me with this please.

Thanks

```
[macro-test]   
;exten => s,1,Answer()   
;exten => s,n,Wait(2)   
exten => s,1,Set(AGISIGHUP=no)   
exten => s,n,NoOp(AGISUGHUP: ${AGISIGHUP})   
exten => s,n,Set(CALLED=${MACRO_EXTEN})   
exten => s,n,Set(CALLER=${CUT(CUT(SIP_HEADER(From),@,1),:,2)})  
exten => s,n(action),Set(EXIT=0)  
exten => s,n,Set(TOKEN="")    
exten => s,n,Set(INIT="true")   
exten => s,n,While($[${EXIT}<1])   
exten => s,n,Set(EXIT=1)   
exten => s,n,Agi(agi://${ARG1}/server.agi?caller=${CALLER}&called=${CALLED}&init=${INIT})   
exten => s,n,Set(INIT="false")   
exten => s,n,NoOp(AGISTATUS: ${AGISTATUS})    
exten => s,n,GotoIf($["${AGISTATUS}" != "SUCCESS"]?fail:succ)   
exten => s,n(succ),EndWhile()   
exten => s,n,Set(INIT="end")   
exten => s,n,Agi(agi://${ARG1}/server.agi?caller=${CALLER}&called=${CALLED}&init=${INIT})   
exten => s,n,Hangup()   
exten => s,n(fail),Wait(2)   
exten => s,n,Playback(vm-goodbye)   
exten => s,n,Hangup()   

exten => h,1,NoOp(Notify Billing System)   
exten => h,n,NoOp(Other Tasks)   
exten => h,n,Hangup()
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple loop dialplan

```
exten =>s ,1,Set(loop=3)
exten =>s,n(loop),Noop(loop start here)
exten =>s,n,Noop(do something here)
exten =>s,n,Set(loop=$[ ${loop} - 1 ]);decrease loop countr
exten =>s,n,GotoIf($[ ${loop} > 0 ]?loop); if still have something, do again
```

Answer (score 0):

> exten => h,n,Hangup()

Don't call hangup, when you're already hung up.